# Wildfly 10 Not using database but getting a jpa error

Tags: eclipse, jpa, wildfly

I recently installed Wildfly-10.0.0.Final.  To get my feet wet, I created an elementary EJB that does not require a database connection.  For some reason when I try to deploy the EJB, I get the following error:

> Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"JavaEE_Wildfly1.jar\".
>       FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.
>       \"JavaEE_Wildfly1.jar\".
>       FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"JavaEE_Wildfly1.jar\" 
>       Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: WFLYJPA0057: PersistenceProvider 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider' not found"}}

Since I am not using a database, do I still have to specify a Persistence provider?  I do not have a persistence.xml because I did not think I needed one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a persistence.xml. Check out this [EJB-In-A-War](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/ejb-in-war) wildfly quickstart for an example of a @Stateless EJB deployed without a persistence.xml.